# Page Scrolling left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create a webpage like http://seller.flipkart.com . I want to  scroll my page first from up to down and then left to right using scrolling button only and background drawing. Can you tell me how can i do this and  which languages should i learn?

```
     $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: -$(sectionName).offset().left}, "slow");
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(sectionName).offset().top}, "slow");
```

Comment: `scrollLeft: document.width-$(sectionName).offset().left`

Answer (score 0):

The effect you are talking about is known as parallax effect.
Use this skollr plug-in (demo link : http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)